# Automatically deletion of row

Tags: php, mysql

I am working a database where, I insert a row in a particular table. Then for some reason I update the same row from the same table and then fetch the values from that row in a html form. Now, the issue is when I do this, the first time I fetch the values it is correctly functioning. The next time I do this (normally after 12 to 24 hours) the values are not being fetched. I checked the database, the table no longer holds the record that I updated earlier. I am confused over this. Is there any solution for this. Please help. Thanks.

Here is my update query that I use to update the record :

```
$upd = "update billingrates set FirstCopyFront='".$firstcopy1."', FirstCopyFB='".$firstcopy2."', Upto50F='".$Lfiftycopies1."', Upto50FB='".$Lfiftycopies2."', Morethan50F='".$Mfiftycopies1."', Morethan50FB='".$Mfiftycopies2."', PrinterType='".$printertype."' where PaperTypeId = '".$id."' and CustomerId = '".$cid."'";
```

And this is how I am getting the values from previous form that I am using for updation :

```
$firstcopy1 = trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['firstcopy'][0]));
                            $firstcopy2 = trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['firstcopy'][1]));
                            $Lfiftycopies1 = trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Lfiftycopies'][0]));
                            $Lfiftycopies2 = trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Lfiftycopies'][1]));
                            $Mfiftycopies1 = trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Mfiftycopies'][0]));
                            $Mfiftycopies2 = trim(mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['Mfiftycopies'][1]));
```

Comment: Please put some code to understand the context

Comment: For this share the schema design and update code(if your doing this programatically).

Comment: if you paste some code.it will be useful for us to understand..

Comment: @2k.silvio  I have edited my question. Please see above.

Comment: @Sucharitha Same for you.

Comment: @user3663 Please see above.